# How to access the native element projected by ng-content

Tags: angular, angular-content-projection

This is my parent component html

```
<app-card>
  <div class="body">This is body</div>
  <div class="title">This is title</div>
</app-card>
```

This is my CardComponent

```
<div class="card">
            <ng-content  select=".title"></ng-content>
            <ng-content select=".body"></ng-content>
</div>
```

So I want to access this element (`<div class="body">This is body</div>`) in the CardComponent,
If it was a component I could have access it by ContentChild but how to access this?

I tried using template variable (passing the variable name in the ContentChild) and tried to access it form ngAfterContentInit getting undefined

Comment: how about use native "document.querySelector('.body')" inside code of component? Also - it would be easy to help - if you post stackblitz which demonstrates the problem

Comment: Thanks @happyZZR1400 , This will be some hacky way to do that, I just want to check if there is any support from angular.

Comment: I you see you need to do some hacky tricks to achieve your goal - it may be a sign that you can do things using some other approach, can you explain in more details - what r u trying to do?

Comment: I plan is to understand ContentChild, everywhere, there are lots example of getting component is given, but nowhere accessing a native element projected in the component is not given, I want to figure it out how to do that

Comment: the idea behind the "ng-content" is: put here what you want and it will be rendered inside parent component. So i guess your idea:to make parent to know the native elements of children - it is little bit against the angular-guys idea (according to them parent should be agnositc)

Comment: Their multiple arguments can be made if in my parent component we have like `app-card>nestedCard+someDiv` here in the AppCardCompoent accessing nestedCard is very easy but no way to access someDiv

Comment: anyway: parent and child can "talk" using services or "Inputs" (may be this what you need)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

- .html

  `<div #myDiv class="body">This is body</div>`
- .ts

  ```
  @ViewChild('myDiv', {static: false}) div: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      // now access div here
      console.log(this.div.nativeElement);
  }
  ```

Here, a reference to the variable `myDiv` is fetched by using the @ViewChild directive. Once the view for the component has initialized, you will have the corresponding element in the `ngAfterViewInit()`.

The `this.div` value can be passed using an *EventEmitter* or a *shared service*. Now you can subscribe/listen for this change in the child component.

Comment: I think you missed the part `<div #myDiv class="body">This is body</div>` is passed from parent compoenent in the child component all I have is  `<ng-content select=".body"></ng-content>` and using template reference here doesnot work, I checked

Comment: Oh okay.. Maybe now in the `ngAfterViewInit()`, you can emit `this.div` value using an EventEmitter or a shared service. Now you can subscribe/listen to this change in the child component. Does that work for you?

Comment: Yes, it works, easily it can be done by `document.querySelector` as commented above, but I want to see if it is achievable by ContentChild. As far as I understand the purpose of ContentChild is to access things that are projected to compoenent, how come such a simple solution is not there. Any way thanks